# CodeIgniter not allowing equal sign in query search term?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller that is accepting a encoded code and setting it as a session variable. I am then trying to look up that code in the DB.

When I print out the query string, it is being excluded for some reason.

```
/**
 * Pass our signup code for demo purposes
 */
public function c(){

    // Did we come here from a Sign-up Pin?
    $registerPin = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if($registerPin){
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'registerPin'  => $registerPin
        ));
    }

    // Redirect to register
    redirect(site_url("register"));

}
```

**Model:**

```
/**
 * Check to see if a pin is a valid demo pin.
 */
public function check_register_pin($pin){

    $s=$this->db
        ->where(array("p.IsDemoPin" => '1', "p.Denomination" => 20, "p.Pin" => $pin))
        ->where("PinID NOT IN (select PinID from customer_pins where `PinID` = '$pin')")
        ->get("pins as p");

    // If this pin was valid and not used, return true.
    if ($s->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Config:**

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-';
```

Example Pin I am trying to look up:

`ebe83beb61277ab20882b68444cc93e10391d230758847f85e97428d95b7022aab6cdabff6cac097f2e79ceb2df56e06b227063f627341b97346abdc03106d28sXhvJ2tlUzkAGdGwjuKM6O137GlP5tQ1kvazNFnj/f4=`

**Printed Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `pins` as `p` WHERE `p`.`IsDemoPin` = '1' AND `p`.`Denomination` = 20 AND `p`.`Pin` = 'ebe83beb61277ab20882b68444cc93e10391d230758847f85e97428d95b7022aab6cdabff6cac097f2e79ceb2df56e06b227063f627341b97346abdc03106d28sXhvJ2tlUzkAGdGwjuKM6O137GlP5tQ1kvazNFnj' AND `PinID` NOT IN (select PinID from customer_pins where `PinID` = 'ebe83beb61277ab20882b68444cc93e10391d230758847f85e97428d95b7022aab6cdabff6cac097f2e79ceb2df56e06b227063f627341b97346abdc03106d28sXhvJ2tlUzkAGdGwjuKM6O137GlP5tQ1kvazNFnj')
```

Comment: why are you generating a *pin* in that format, wouldn't a sha256 suffice?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am using an encryption library `$this->encryption->encrypt('value')` and that is the result of it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I see that now, trying to figure out how to solve it. A simple `urlencode()` doesnt seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the class your using to encrypt the value returns a base64 encoded string. Which contains a `/` and it breaks your routing when used in the url.

Base64 is *not* url safe because it contains `/`, `+` and `=` characters.

You could work around this issue by decoding what the function returns and then encoding it in a url safe way, which you can then use without issues in the url path:

```
<?php
/**
 * Decode a url-safe base64 string.
 */
function base64_urldecode($str) {
    $pad = strlen($str) % 4;
    if ($pad) {
        $padlen = 4 - $pad;
        $str .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
    }
    return base64_decode(strtr($str, '-_', '+/'));
}

/**
 * Encode a string into url safe base64.
 */
function base64_urlencode($str) {
    return str_replace('=', '', strtr(base64_encode($str), '+/', '-_'));
}

$code = base64_decode('ebe83beb61277ab20882b68444cc93e10391d230758847f85e97428d95b7022aab6cdabff6cac097f2e79ceb2df56e06b227063f627341b97346abdc03106d28sXhvJ2tlUzkAGdGwjuKM6O137GlP5tQ1kvazNFnj/f4=');

echo base64_urlencode($code);
```

Would output `_f4` instead of `/f4=`: